# How to hit my Api from locally served angular app?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, localhost

I deployed and API locally, built with .NET Core 5, its CORS is configured to accept any request from any website or client it is also running locally from my network, so I can hit my API from another PC using PostMan (already tested).

I run the following command in my angular app to serve it locally.

```
ng serve --host 192.168.0.12    -- or 
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

This command allows me to view my user interface from my Android phone, but when I try to hit the API from my android, it does not let me... however, if hit my API from my main machine using the `192.168.0.12:4200` address, it does work.

I already added an inbound rule in the firewall to accept any traffic from the 4200 port.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some advice on this. Thanks in advance.

[image: error on android chrome browser]

Comment: Postman does not have any CORS rules, so it will allow the request.  Browsers do have CORS rules and will not allow wild-cards for allowed-hosts when sending credentials.  Localhosts with different ports are treated as separate domains.

Comment: So i am guessing that this approach is out of the question...

Comment: Might need a [proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) back to the local running app.

Comment: I just use a browser profile with CORS turned off for ng serve debugging.  (disable security)  If you're going to publish the site you'd just include the output of ng build in your ASP.NET project (right-click on special wwwroot folder, and choose "Add Existing File", and select all the files angular builds in "dist" directory.   When hitting the published site you will be same-domain.  (You'll also avoid reducing security by not needing to set CORS headers)

Comment: Well the idea was just to hit API from google chrome app in android without publishing the angular app, I doubt i can turn off CORS in google chrome App for android.

Comment: @AndrewS I tried proxying the back end server, i have two bindings in my IIS server, one binding is for my localhost (host PC), and my other binding is pointing to my host ip address so other devices in my network can hit my API. I created the proxy.conf.json and followed the instructions in the DOCS, but no luck man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's tools. In particular proxying to a backend server.
With this tool you can divert certain URLs to a backend server.

> For example, to divert all calls for `http://localhost:4200/api` to a server running on `http://localhost:3000/api`, take the following steps.
>
> 1. Create a file `proxy.conf.json` in your project's `src/` folder.
> 2. Add the following content to the new proxy file:
>
> ```
> {
>   "/api": {
>    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
>     "secure": false
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> 3. In the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`, add the `proxyConfig` option to the `serve` target:
>
> ```
> …
>   "architect": {
>     "serve": {
>       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
>       "options": {
>         "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
>         "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
>       },
> …
> ```
>
> 4. To run the development server with this proxy configuration, call `ng serve`.

You can find the official guide at the following link: [Proxying to a backend server](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)